# Changing the field separator of awk to newline

Tags: awk

The -F option lets you specify the field separator for awk, but using '\n' as the line separator doesn't work, that is, it doesn't make $1 the first line of the input, $2 the second line, and so on.

I suspect that this is because awk looks for the field separator *within each line*. Is there a way to get around this with awk, or some other Linux command? Basically, I want to separate my input by newline characters and put them into an Excel file.

I'm still warming up to Linux and shell scripts, which is the reason for my lack of creativity with this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Its not entirely clear what your inputs are but it sounds like the `paste` command my be useful for this problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may require to overwrite the input record separator (RS), which default is newline.

See my example below,

```
$ cat test.txt
a
b
c
d

$ awk 'BEGIN{ RS = "" ; FS = "\n" }{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' test.txt
a b c d
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can change both the input and output record separator so you can do something like this to achieve a similar result to the accepted answer.

```
cat test.txt 
a
b
c
d
$ awk -v ORS=" " '{print $1}' test.txt 
a b c d
```

Answer (score 0):

one can simplify it to just the following, with a minor caveat of extra trailing space without trailing newline :

```
% echo "a\nb\nc\nd"
a
b
c
d
% echo "a\nb\nc\nd" | mawk 8 ORS=' '
a b c d %
```

To rectify that, plus handling the edge case of no trailing newline from input, one can modify it to :

```
% echo -n "a\nb\nc\nd" | mawk 'NF-=_==$NF' FS='\n' RS='^$' | odview

0000000         543301729       174334051                                
           a       b       c       d  \n                                
          141 040 142 040 143 040 144 012                                
           a  sp   b  sp   c  sp   d  nl                                
           97  32  98  32  99  32 100  10                                
           61  20  62  20  63  20  64  0a                                

0000010

% echo "a\nb\nc\nd" | mawk 'NF -= (_==$NF)' FS='\n' RS='^$' | odview 

0000000         543301729       174334051                                
           a       b       c       d  \n                                
          141 040 142 040 143 040 144 012                                
           a  sp   b  sp   c  sp   d  nl                                
           97  32  98  32  99  32 100  10                                
           61  20  62  20  63  20  64  0a                                

0000010
```